# NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

I keep getting the above mentioned error. I have deleted the existing db field `id` which was set to unique. But on save I got the below exception

```
raise NotUniqueError(message % unicode(err))
NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error index: test.users.$id_1  dup key: { : null })
```

My `user` table looks like,

```
class Users(db.Document, UserMixin):
    name = db.StringField(max_length=50)
    email = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255)
    city = db.StringField(max_length=125)
    active = db.BooleanField(default=True)
    company =  db.StringField(max_length=255)
    type = db.StringField(max_length=15)
    confirmed_at = db.DateTimeField()
    role = db.ReferenceField(Role)

    meta = {'strict': False}
```

I also tried unsetting the `id` attribute using,

```
cls.objects.update(**{"unset__id": 1})
```

But it throws this exception,

```
raise OperationError(u'Update failed (%s)' % unicode(err))
OperationError: Update failed (Mod on _id not allowed)
```

I just want to save the user model without `id` field.

Comment: What is the UserMixin class?

Comment: it's from flask_security package `from flask.ext.security import UserMixin`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If call [`list_indexes()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?#mongoengine.Document.list_indexes) it will show an unique index on the `id` field.

You need to drop the unique index on the `id` field in the collection as well using [`db.collection.dropIndex()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/).

I am not sure if mongoengine provides a `drop_index` class method but you can do this from the shell.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer**

You can use db.collectionName.dropIndexes() to drop all the indexes got created on the database level except the _id index. Also you can manually drop the indexes using [db.collectionName.dropIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/)

**My Question**

I have got a similar issue after passing unique_with constraint on some fields and even after removing the unique_with constraint from the field & passing unique=False things didn't changed then I looked into database from shell using command db.collectionName.getIndexes() and found that their were indexes created at database level and I was so intrigued knowing this as MongoEngine creates the Schema only at Application level then why did that happened.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32474312)