# NotUniqueError using django and mongoengine

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-mongodb-engine, restframeworkmongoengine

I am using django and mongoengine.
This is the error I am getting time and again when I try to save a newly created instance using .save() method.I was able to create a model  instance first time but after that any post request is raising this error.
Here's my Document structure:

```
class Client(DynamicDocument):
   name = fields.StringField(required=True,max_length=30) 
   uuid = fields.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4())
   contactEmail = fields.EmailField(required=True,max_length=30)
   contactPhone = fields.StringField(required=True,max_length=30)
   contactPerson = fields.StringField(required=True,max_length=30)

class ClientSerializer(mongoserializers.DocumentSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('id','name','uuid','contactEmail','contactPhone','contactPerson')
```

and here's where am making post request:

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but i catch the error:

> NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error collection: project.client index: UUID_1 dup key: { : null })

I am stuck here.Please tell me where I went wrong since I am a noob to django.Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

yo need set default as function:
try remove the parentheses:

```
uuid = fields.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4())
#                                         ^^^
```

to

```
uuid = fields.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
#                                        ^^^
```

and try in serializer, declaring uuid field explicitly:

```
class ClientSerializer(mongoserializers.DocumentSerializer):
    uuid = serializers.UUIDField()
```

Comment: I tried doing that,not making any difference.Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: can you show your `request.data`? add it to the question please

Comment: {u'contactEmail': u'ville@gmail.com', u'contactPhone': u'7878787878', u'name': u'bournc', u'contactPerson': u'singh'}
this is my request.data

Comment: OrderedDict([(u'name', u'bournc'), (u'uuid', UUID('a098889d-7c13-4ee5-8317-a9051cbd1258')), (u'contactEmail', u'ville@gmail.com'), (u'contactPhone', u'7878787878'), (u'contactPerson', u'singh')]) and this is serializer.validated_data before serializer.save() method is called.

Comment: did you try delete index: [duplicate-unique-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716486/notuniqueerror-tried-to-save-duplicate-unique-keys) ?

Comment: Hey  @Bear Brown thanks for the solution.Deleting index worked.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a web framework that basically relies on a relational backend (eg sql) to save all its models. On the other hand MongoEngine is a ORM wrapper around MongoDB. Django has its own ORM type wrapper in the form of models.

To use Django with MongoEngine, either try Django-nonrel or try [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) which connects a relational Django to MongoDB.

Using Django Models  with MongoEngine will not work always. Alternatively It's better to use MongoEngine ORM to save your models.